# Enumerating ruby dictionary keys using dictionary entries

Tags: ruby, vagrant

Apologies for the messy sounding title, didn't know how to phrase this in a concise way...

I'm looking to create a general purpose Vagrantfile for various test purposes using a dictionary like the one below.

```
BOXES = {
  'bo': ['zesty-lxc', 4],
  'sw': ['zesty-lxc', 4],
  'db': ['centos-lxc', 4]
}
```

Which would give me a list like below:

```
[
  ["bo1", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["bo2", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["bo3", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["bo4", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["sw1", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["sw2", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["sw3", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["sw4", "zesty-lxc"],
  ["db1", "centos-lxc"],
  ["db2", "centos-lxc"],
  ["db3", "centos-lxc"],
  ["db4", "centos-lxc"]
]
```

that I can then iterate through later to create machines.

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  box_list.each do |box, name|
    config.vm.define name do |subconfig|
      subconfig.vm.box = box
      subconfig.vm.hostname = name
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having a bit of trouble managing this. I've managed to print exactly what I want using this very messy construct:

```
BOXES.map{|key, v| ([key]*BOXES[key][1]).each.with_index(1) {|machine, count| puts "#{machine}#{count} #{BOXES[key][0]}" }}
```

but it only prints, I can't figure out how to get it to return the list that I'm intending to use later.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm very new to ruby, only started using it when I started messing around with vagrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

```
# We will assume this is what you meant for BOXES
BOXES = {
  bo: ['zesty-lxc', 4],
  sw: ['zesty-lxc', 4],
  db: ['centos-lxc', 4]
} 
BOXES.map do |key,value|
  os, number = value # assign value[0] to os and value[1] to number
  number.times.map {|n| [key.to_s + (n + 1).to_s, os] }
end.flatten(1) # flatten the Array 1 level 
#=> [
#     ["bo1", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["bo2", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["bo3", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["bo4", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["sw1", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["sw2", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["sw3", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["sw4", "zesty-lxc"],
#     ["db1", "centos-lxc"],
#     ["db2", "centos-lxc"],
#     ["db3", "centos-lxc"],
#     ["db4", "centos-lxc"]
#   ]
```

Steps:

- `BOXES#map` will create a new `Array` and yield each key and value to the block
- `os, number = value` will assign value[0] to `os` and value[1] to `number`
- `number.times.map` will create a new `Array` and will loop through `number` number of times passing in each integer (`n`), starting with `0` as it loops
- `[key.to_s + (n + 1).to_s, os]` will create a literal `Array` with [0] = key and number + 1 combined as a String and [1] = value
- `flatten(1)` will remove the `Array` nesting created by `number.times.map`

Comment: That's amazing, works flawlessly.

I really should learn ruby just to get my head around this amazing SUGAR! Python's always going to be my main go-to, but this just looks so fun!

Answer (score 1):

```
result = BOXES.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), memo| 
  (1 .. v.last).each do |i| 
    memo << [k.to_s + i.to_s, v.first]
  end
end
```